# Convert rupees amount into words

Tags: javascript

I have to convert rupees amount into words in **javascript**. Here **ConvertToHundreds** is the function to convert hundred, tens and ones value.

```
var aUnits = ["Thousand", "Lacs", "Crore", "Arab", "Kharab" ];
var cWords; 

var nLeft = Math.floor(s);
var st = new String(nLeft);
for (var i = 0; nLeft > 0; i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    cWords += ConvertToHundreds(nLeft) + " " + aUnits[i-1] + " " +cWords;
  } else {
    cWords = ConvertToHundreds(nLeft) + " ";
  }

  if (st.length <= 5) {
    nLeft = Math.floor(nLeft / 1000);
  } else if (st.length > 5 && st.length <= 7){
    nLeft = Math.floor(nLeft / 1000) / 100;
    //~ console.log(i);
    i++;
  } else if (st.length > 7 && st.length <= 9) {
    nLeft = Math.floor(nLeft / 1000) /10000;
    i+=2;
  } else if (st.length > 9 && st.length <= 11){
    nLeft = Math.floor(nLeft / 1000) /1000000;
    i+=3;
  } else {
    nLeft = Math.floor(nLeft / 1000) /100000000;
    i+=4;
  }
}

s = Math.round(s * 100) % 100;
var rupee = "Ruppes " + cWords;
if (s > 0)
  cWords = rupee + "and Paise " + ConvertToHundreds(s) + " Only";
else
  cWords = rupee + "Only";

return cWords;
```

This code not displaying thousand value.
ex.: 5,01,000.00 returns Rupees Five Lacs Only

Comment: I corrected the indentation, please indent properly next time. From what I can tell, the function definition is missing. Also please provide more sample input and output so everybody can tell what the function should do.

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

INDIAN AMOUNT,PRICE CURRENCY Display IN TO WORDS BASED ON INPUT NUMBER
Input : 1250000000
Result :  One Hundred and Twenty Five Crore
Input : 1250000
Result : 12.50 Lac(s)

```
function price_in_words(price) {
            var sglDigit = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"],
                dblDigit = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"],
                tensPlace = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"],
                handle_tens = function(dgt, prevDgt) {
                    return 0 == dgt ? "" : " " + (1 == dgt ? dblDigit[prevDgt] : tensPlace[dgt])
                },
                handle_utlc = function(dgt, nxtDgt, denom) {
                    return (0 != dgt && 1 != nxtDgt ? " " + sglDigit[dgt] : "") + (0 != nxtDgt || dgt > 0 ? " " + denom : "")
                };

                var str = "",
                    digitIdx = 0,
                    digit = 0,
                    nxtDigit = 0,
                    words = [];
                if (price += "", isNaN(parseInt(price))) str = "";
                else if (parseInt(price) > 0 && price.length <= 10) {
                    for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) switch (digit = price[digitIdx] - 0, nxtDigit = digitIdx > 0 ? price[digitIdx - 1] - 0 : 0, price.length - digitIdx - 1) {
                        case 0:
                            words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Crore"));
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] || 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : " Crore") : "")
                    }
                    str = words.reverse().join("")
                } else str = "";
                return str

        }

        alert(price_in_words(1250000000));

        function price_in_num_words(price) {
            var result = "",
            priceInNum = parseFloat(price),
            priceStr = new String(price);
            if (!isNaN(priceInNum)) {
                var x = priceStr.split("."),
                intLength = x[0].length;
                result = intLength <= 3 ? priceInNum.toFixed(1) : intLength <= 5 ? (priceInNum / 1e3).toFixed(1) + " Thousand" : intLength <= 7 ? (priceInNum / 1e5).toFixed(2) + " Lac(s)" : intLength <= 9 ? (priceInNum / 1e7).toFixed(2) + " Cr(s)" : "More than One Hundred Cr(s)"
            }
            return result
          }
         alert(price_in_num_words(1250000));
```